# change script language (only) in FileMaker?

Tags: macos, scripting, filemaker

I'm using FileMaker 18 in my non-english locale, and that's good for dates, numbers, etc.

However, as I'm still learning FileMaker, having all the script steps translated is rather troublesome because most tutorials and examples are in English. I can translate them and find the proper steps in my language, but sometimes it is not perfectly clear which of two or three translations is correct and anyway it's a step that shouldn't be necessary.

Is there a way to tell FileMaker (18 Pro Advanced) to use English as the script language, and only there, or is it always tied to the system settings?

This is on MacOS 10.14

Comment: You'll likely want to specify which OS you're running FileMaker on, as well.

Comment: @pft221 true, sorry for leaving that out - MacOS (added to question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface/program language is tied to the system language, if that language is one of the supported languages. If not, the program defaults to English. The language affects the whole program, there is no way to have different language for parts of the program.

Date and numbering format follows the system setting for date/time/numbering, independently of the program language. (There is however a known bug in the the display formatting of dates in non-supported languages where / is used as separator regardless of the system setting.)

You may be able to force the program over to English if you remove the resource for your locale.

Answer (score 3):

To disable a language in FileMaker, do the following:

In Finder:

- right click on the FileMaker.app, and
- select 'Show package contents'
- navigate to the Contents/Resources folder and
- locate the *.lproj sub-folder for your language (e.g. de.lproj for german)
- and then

  - delete it - to permanently remove the language,
  - or move it to somewhere else on your drive - so you can put it back later, if you want.

Comment: That's an interesting hack, actually.

Answer (score 2):

> I can translate them and find the proper steps in my language, but sometimes it is not perfectly clear which of two or three translations is correct

You can get an *exact* translation by finding the script step in the English online help, then changing the URL slightly to get the same page in another language. For example, starting with:

```
https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/en/#page/FMP_Help%2Fallow-user-abort.html%23
```

you can replace the `/en/` path segment with `/de/` to get the German version of the same page:

```
https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/de/#page/FMP_Help%2Fallow-user-abort.html%23
```

This could be automated.